# iOS: How can I achieve design with dynamic length text?

Tags: ios, objective-c

How can I make a simple design like in the image below where text length is dynamic? In the image below there are two sections Ingredients and Instructions with dynamic text length. There could be more sections.

Should I go for UIView with a UIScrollView or Table View? Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like a perfect example for UITableView. You can use NSString methods to calculate the size that your string will have. This size you can return from `- tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` delegate method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this approach.

**1.** Use `UITextView` this will give you possibility to scroll text inside `UITextView` if text will be very big.

**2.** Get the size of you text view 
// return the size for UITextView for both IOS7 and IOS6

```
-(CGSize) getSizeWithMaxLabelSize:(CGSize) maxLabelSize forTextViewWithText:(NSString *) text  
{
    CGSize expectedLabelSize;
    CGSize maximumLabelSize = maxLabelSize;
    if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN(@"6.2")) {
        NSDictionary *stringAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[UIFont   fontWithName:@"Arial" size:12] forKey: NSFontAttributeName];
        CGRect rect =[text boundingRectWithSize:maximumLabelSize options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:stringAttributes context:nil];
        expectedLabelSize = rect.size;
        expectedLabelSize.height = ceilf(expectedLabelSize.height);
        expectedLabelSize.width  = ceilf(expectedLabelSize.width);
} else {
       expectedLabelSize = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial"  size:EPCommentViewFontSize] constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize  lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
}    
       return expectedLabelSize;
}
```

**3.**  Use this method (2) when you calculate cell height for you table 
`- tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

Comment: I used a solution something like this.

Answer (score 0):

You should go for `UITextView`/`UILabel` with `UIScrollView`. UILabel is preferable if the content is not editable and you do not need the text scrolling on the fixed area.

If your needs fulfilled by these, you need to go with `UILabel` with `UIScrollView`.